# How to replace a value with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find `H2`s in a string, and replace them to add an `id` to each `H2`.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(blogsContent);
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2"))
{
   var testing = node.OuterHtml.Replace("<h2>", "<h2 id=\"" + node.InnerText + "\">");
   // This does the job and changes the <h2> to a <h2 id="..."
}
var html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; 
// However, here, the whole document after the foreach does not include any of the replacements.
```

How do I make `var html` have all the changes which the `foreach` should be implementing?

I've looked over StackOverflow, and can't really find an identical question which solves my issue. I apologise if I'm being daft.

Comment: you construct the `testing` var but you don't set it back to the node content. That said, why don't you `node.SetAttributeValue("Id",node.InnerText)` ? The whole purpose of HtmlAgilityPack is to avoid manipulating strings

Comment: Oh, @SteveB. I love you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(@"
    <div>
        <h2>val 1</h2>
        <h2>val 2</h2>
        <h2>val 3</h2>
    </div>  
    ");
    foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2"))
    {
       node.SetAttributeValue("id",node.InnerText);
       // This does the job and changes the <h2> to a <h2 id="..."
    }
    var html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; 
    Console.WriteLine(html);
```

As I said in my comment, the purpose (and benefits) of HTMLAgilityPack is to avoid string manipulation.

Imagine some of you `h2` contains forbidden characters like `Why "><script>alert("bang")</script></h2> <h2> should be escaped ?` (especially true when allowing external user input, like comments in blog)

this would lead to :

```
<h2 id="Why "><script>alert("bang")</script> <h2> should be escaped ?">val 1</h2>
```

which is obviously a dangerous flaw (leads to XSS attacks)